# Swift - Filtering custom array with a property issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have custom class for "answers". And I'm trying to sort them all by its createdTimestamp property (It's optional too). But sometimes I'm getting crash with forced unwrap like below.

```
allAnswerItems = allAnswerItems.sorted(by: { $0.createdTimestamp! > $1.createdTimestamp! })
```

That's why I have tried to resolve that using below code blocks. It looks work. But I want to understand It will match with my all expectations in any case. Hopefully not crash anymore.

Will the return types for first and second affect the results in there?

Decreasingly:

```
allAnswerItems = allAnswerItems.sorted(by: {
     guard let first: String = $0.createdTimestamp else { return false }
     guard let second: String = $1.createdTimestamp else { return true }
     return first > second
})
```

Increasingly:

```
allAnswerItems = allAnswerItems.sorted(by: {
     guard let first: String = $0.createdTimestamp else { return false }
     guard let second: String = $1.createdTimestamp else { return true }
     return first < second
})
```

And also checking contains.

```
if !self.allAnswerItems.contains(where: { $0.answerKey! == key }) {
     // do things.
}
```

Will it cover the safe unwrap for optionals?

```
let isContainData = self.allAnswerItems.contains(where: {
     guard let first: String = $0.answerKey else { return false }
     return first == key
})

if !isContainData {
     // do things.                                                 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, have you tried your second sort code? If so what is the issue with it? Off-topic, the name `createdTimestamp` implies, at least to me, a property that isn't optional.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the code block, It works. But I want to make sure that it will work as expected both increasing and decreasing side. I have update and added more details above.

Comment: I'm using NSCoding class. That's why I preferred using createdTimestamp as optional.

Comment: I would decide how to sort nil values, always first or always last. Right now you have the same logic in your guard statements for both descending and ascending sorting, shouldn't they be the opposite of each other?